# How do I get collaborator access to the Google Glass API?

Tags: google-api, google-glass, google-api-console

A Glass explorer has given me owner access to a Appengine project which he enabled the Google Mirror API on (we both have owner access). However, when I view the project in my user console it tells me no APIs are enabled and the API does not appear in the available services I can turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have access to the Google Mirror API on that project, you just can't see it.

Only those who are whitelisted can see the Google Mirror API on the [services panel](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#%3aservices) of the Google APIs Console. This means if your collaborator enables the Google Mirror API on your project, you can access the API keys but not see or control the API.

Comment: Okay, thank you, would love to see this fixed to avoid confusion.

Comment: Agreed. This should probably show up as a disabled toggle to you. I'll follow up with the API Console team.